# Is there a way to customize the Drill execution plan?

Tags: apache-drill

We want to execute a query using Drill with the PostGIS storage plugin, the query is:

```sql
SELECT zone, count(primary_roads.id) as roads
FROM pg.test.zones, pg.test.primary_roads
WHERE ST_Crosses(geom_linestring, geom)
AND zone IN ('Astoria Park', 'Red Hook', 'Douglaston')
GROUP BY zone
ORDER BY roads desc;
```

Adding logs to Drill we see that what actually Drill does is splitting the query in two parts:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "test"."primary_roads"
```

And

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "test"."zones"
WHERE "zone" = 'Astoria Park' OR "zone" = 'Red Hook' OR "zone" = 'Douglaston'
```

As you can see, it does not include the ST_Crosses function, also the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses.

So, is there a way we can pass the entirely query to PostGIS and avoid the splitting?

Answer (score 0):

Internally Drill's planner has decided that this is the best way to run the query, and unfortunately there is no way to explicitly tell Drill not to do this. To make the planner behave differently and pushdown the **ST_Crosses** function along with the group by and order by we would have to make some code changes. If you'd like to see this optimization done in Drill please get in touch with the Drill team on the mailing lists. You can find all the mailing list information [here](http://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/).